# Nested foreach loop issue

Tags: php, foreach, nested

I am trying to get this nested `foreach` loop to work, but I've had no luck. Here is my code.

```
$q = 0;
$arrayCountTwo = count($_POST['quantity']);
$i = 0;
$arrayCountThree = count($_POST['items']);
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $items) {
    $sql = '';
    foreach ($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity) {
        $q++;
        if ($q > $arrayCountTwo) {
            break;
        } else {
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO `trade_show_reserved` (ProductID, DateReserved, DateReservedEnd, QuantityReserved) VALUES ('".$items."','".$startDate."', '".$endDate."','".$quantity."')";
        }
        var_dump($sql);
    }   
}
```

It keeps giving me the first value in the `$items` array on each iteration. How do I fix this?

Here is the arrays you requested.

The items array and the quantity array in order.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

It should be doing this each time.

```
INSERT INTO `ts_table` (ProductID, DateReserved, DateReservedEnd, QuantityReserved) VALUES ('11','2013-4-11', '2013-4-25','1')

INSERT INTO `ts_table` (ProductID, DateReserved, DateReservedEnd, QuantityReserved) VALUES ('6','2013-4-11', '2013-4-25','2')
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, look at what appears to be a gaping SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: I'm aware of the sql issues. I just want to get the loop working first on my local environment.

Comment: Show us your `items` and `quantity` arrays?

Comment: Why you are using `foreach` here? You can implement it more effectively with `for`.

Comment: I want my first item to go into my sql query just like my quantity is right now.

Comment: @netme, I'd prefer `foreach`. It's for these situations. `for` isn't really for iterating over an array; it's for iterating over a counter.

Comment: There it is MicheelRushton. The arrays are in the edit.

Comment: Is there any relation between both arrays, because you seem to bee looping over two unrelated arrays?

Comment: Yeah, they both belong in this query and I am collecting this data from an ajax call.

Comment: We see what it *is* doing, what is it *supposed* to be doing?

Comment: If you only want the first item the just do: `$_POST['items'][0]`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want `$_POST['items'][0]` to be paired with `$_POST['quantity'][0]`, `$_POST['items'][1]` with `$_POST['quantity'][1]` etc. or `$_POST['items'][0]` with every entry in `$_POST['quantity']` (which is what you are currently almost achieving)?

Comment: @deceze, its in my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $key => $items)
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `trade_show_reserved` (ProductID, DateReserved, DateReservedEnd, QuantityReserved) VALUES ('".$items."','".$startDate."','".$endDate."','".$_POST['quantity'][$key]."')";
  echo $sql . '<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could loop through my quantity like that within this loop. Good to know MichaelRushton. Thanks guys for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0, $iMax = min(count($_POST['items']), count($_POST['quantity'])); $i < $iMax; $i++)
{
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO `trade_show_reserved` (ProductID, DateReserved, DateReservedEnd, QuantityReserved) VALUES ('".$_POST['items'][$i]."','".$startDate."', '".$endDate."','".$_POST['quantity'][$i]."')";
}
```

Is more along the lines of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. Assuming that `item[1]` and `quantity[1]` are related;

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $idx => $item) {
    // get the quantity with the same index as the item
    // if it does not exist, default to zero
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity'][$idx]) ? $_POST['quantity'][$idx] : 0;

    // insert query... 

}
```